Recoverably recompress gzip files into zstd, preserving original checksums?
I need to archive a lot of gzip-compressed data. The problem is that compared to zstd, gzip is wasteful, both in terms of ratio and CPU time required to decompress the data. Because of that, I want to recompress the data into zstd. Unfortunately, I need to be able to reconstruct the SHA/MD5 checksums of the original compressed gzip files, in order to prove its origin.
Is it possible? If the gzip algorithm was deterministic, that would be trivial, but I don't have access to information about which version of gzip was used, what was the compression level etc.

Preserving what original checksums? The gzip or the files inside of it? Are you trying to compress the gzip file itself to zstd or extract them first? Or are you just wanting to checksum the .gz before compressing it to .zst?  Do you want to compress all of the gzip files in individual .zst's or all of them in one big .zst  file?

You should record the checksums of the uncompressed files, and then extract them when you need to validate them. This way the compression method you use doesn't matter.

@larsks the problem is that this is beyond my control. Data supplier publishes SHA1 sums of gzip files. I want to archive them in a more efficient format, but also deliver them to whoever wants them in a format that allows for verification that this is the exact same data coming from that supplier.
